# ggplot retain duplicate colors for combined plots

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, geospatial

I'm trying to create a map of all the ethnicities in the world - based on a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` (shape files can be downloaded [here](http://www.icr.ethz.ch/data/other/greg/GREG.zip)). My problem is that `ggplot` appears to reassign colors after each consecutive call to `geom_polygon`. The following code for two countries works fine and all the areas/ethnicities can be distinguished from each other.

```
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(rms)
library(igraph)
library(foreign)
library(sp)
library(spdep)
library(ggplot2)

setwd("yourdirectory")

# load GREG dataset
greg <- readShapePoly("GREG.shp", proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")) 
# exclude very small polygons (<= 5 square km)
greg <- greg[greg$AREA > 1000e+06,]


dev.off()
temp <- greg[greg$COW==325,]
g<-ggplot(temp, aes(x = long, y = lat))  + 
   geom_polygon(data=temp,aes(group = group, fill=group, size=1))

temp <- greg[greg$COW==225,]
g + 
  geom_polygon(data=temp,aes(group = group, fill=group, size=1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

However when I run this code in a loop and on a large number of polygons (countries in this case), the color of many polygons (check out Italy and Switzerland) become indistinguishable from each other, because ggplot assigns a unique color to each one (there are apparently 6011 polygons). is there a way to keep the "non-unique" colors of each polygon in the combined plot? In other words the plot should allow duplicate colors.

```
dev.off()
temp <- greg[greg$COW==0,]
g <- ggplot(temp, aes(x = long, y = lat)) + 
  geom_polygon(data=temp,aes(group = group,  fill=group, size=1))


for (cow in unique(greg$COW)) {
  if (cow==0) next
  temp <- greg[greg$COW==cow,]
  g <- g + 
    geom_polygon(data=temp, aes(group = group, fill=group, size=1))
}
g <- g + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

PS: you might have to export the second plot (ie. to PNG) in order to actually see it.

Comment: Would it be possible to make this example a lot more minimal? Couldn't you just generate some random data and run a few `geom_polygon` plots on it in a loop? It's a bit much to ask that people download your data, and there's a lot of details in the code that aren't relevant to the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think it's difficult to recreate the error without the mentioned shape file. But I've reduced the code to a minimum.

Comment: What exactly do you want to assign color based on? R only allows one scale for fill so it tries to make a unique across all values. You have 6011 different groups in the dataset and it's hard to come up with 6011 different colors that are all distinct.

Comment: exactly, that's the issue. the colors should be unique within a country but not within the map. fill=group assigns colors according to ethnicities.

Comment: `fill=group` does not assign colors based on ethnicity. Right now, `fill=group` is just coloring every region a different color even if both regions have the same ethnicity. So, again I ask what exactly you are trying to color by. It looks like you have 148 countries and about 3512 regions defined representing 6011 polygons. Each region has up to three ethnicities assigned. There are about 120 distinct ethnicities. So do you really just want every region a different color within a country regardless of ethnicity?

Comment: Ideally each ethnicity should have the same color for all regions. My idea was initially to set fill=GROUP1, but it seems that ethnicities haven't been assigned to each polygon - or some other issue prevented this attempt. The alternative would be just different colors within a country.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, as I mentioned before, you can only have scale per attribute. So the fill colors don't reset for each country even if you add them as separate layers. In order to perform a coloring like that, you'll need to create your own variable that behaves in that manner. What i've done is used `interaction()` to find the unique combinations of country/ethnicity. Then, i took those values and mapped them to 1:12. I did that with

```
greg$ceid <- (as.numeric(interaction(greg$G1ID, greg$FIPS_CNTRY, drop=T)) %% 12) +1
```

Now this assumes that `FIPS_CNTRY` is a better measure of country than `COW`. It also appears that `G1ID` is a better ID for the particular ethnicity than `GROUP1` across the dataset. If there is documentation for this data set, you'll probably want to carefully read it to verify this information. Most countries have less than 10 ethnicities, but there is one that has 206 and next highest is 87.

So this tried to spread out the colors across countries. The next trick is to use `fortify` explicitly to tell ggplot how to group the regions. We do that with

```
fortify(greg, region="ceid")
```

which produces something that looks like

```
       long      lat order  hole piece group id
1 -158.7752 63.22207     1 FALSE     1   1.1  1
2 -158.7752 63.36345     2 FALSE     1   1.1  1
3 -158.4783 63.54724     3 FALSE     1   1.1  1
4 -158.4359 63.64621     4 FALSE     1   1.1  1
5 -158.3228 63.83000     5 FALSE     1   1.1  1
6 -158.0262 63.98471     6 FALSE     1   1.1  1
```

where the `group` indicates the polygon grouping and the `id` corresponds to the regions we specified in the `fortify`. So these are the numbers 1:12. Now we plot this all with

```
g <- ggplot(fortify(greg, region="ceid"), aes(x = long, y = lat)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group,  fill = id), size=1) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(type="qual", palette = "Set3") + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Here I used a [colorbrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) qualitative color pallete. That looks like this

[image]

If you instead plotted with the actual ethnicities ids for group 1 with the default colors, you could get

```
g <- ggplot(fortify(greg, region="G1ID"), aes(x = long, y = lat)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group,  fill=id), size=1) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

The latter plot is certainly "smoother", but it's really up to you what you want to communicate though the plot.